# Single DbContext using multiple connection strings per environment

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, connection-string, dbcontext

I know that currently a group of developers that I joined do not use Entity Framework, but they are fine with me using it.

Currently their connection strings are stored in `web.config` (or `app.config`)

```
<add name="LH_RPMDB" 
     connectionString="data source=localhostdb;Database=dbsim;user id=sim;password=sim;Application Name=SIM-LH;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DEV_RPMDB" 
     connectionString="data source=devdb;Database=dbsim;user id=sim;password=sim;Application Name=SIM-dev;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="QA_RPMDB" 
     connectionString="data source=qadb;Database=dbsim;user id=sim;password=sim;Application Name=SIM-qa;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now they are telling me to use `LH` for localhost, then upper environments will they fall in line with `DEV` and `QA`.

I'm NOT sure if they are "detecting" the URL for what server as I'm new to the team. I am just trying to get my `DbContext` in place to consume the proper database connection string.

Currently I just have 1 `DbContext` with one connection string and thus

```
public class RPMContext : DbContext
```

But I see that "they" are using code like this:

```
ws.Url = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Environment") + "_SNTRAX")
```

However, I am wanting to leverage the several connection strings for all the environments with a single `DbContext`.

I found some code that shows this example `web.config`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString ...
```

then

```
public TrackerContext() : base("Name=DefaultConnection") {}
```

another example I was seeing is

```
public partial class HOLDbEntities
{
    public HOLDbEntities(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
```

Here is a stackoverflow article I had seen, it doesn't really get me to where I want to be though

[Entity Framework - using the same DbContext with different connection strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092290/entity-framework-using-the-same-dbcontext-with-different-connection-strings)

What do I want?  Well I know that I need to have all the environments connection strings in the `app.config` (not using `web.config` with this project as it is a console application).

What I do not know is how to know what environment that I am in for the application to be somewhat dummy proof and just "automatically "work"

I'm thinking that reading the URL, but actually it is a console application So I wonder if per server environment if there should be an appsetting changed for which connection string to use so  "LH" vs. "DEV" and "QA"  and then a few others...

Thoughts?

Comment: What's the actual problem? Doesn't `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Environment")` tell you then environment? It seems you already know how to obtain the right connection string?!

Comment: The line of code with `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Environment")` is from this other project.  I guess I want to know how to use it with DbContext file

Comment: Can't you just `new HOLDbEntities(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Environment") + ...)`? No need to modify the context .cs file.

Comment: how do i get  `public TrackerContext() : base("Name=DefaultConnection") {}`  to have a method to pass in `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Environment")`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Configuration Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859) perhaps?

Comment: It is a thought I have had, I've used web.config transformations, and then slow cheetah,  so I do understand the purpose .   I am pretty sure this group that I'm temporarily with is not going to be fond of it as they have their methodologies and with a code review they asked me to use their way of using connection strings  ( problem is they are not using dbcontext / ef   , and i also do not know how they are managing the proper environment)

Comment: Can you just get the connection string however they do it, then just pass it in to your DbContext constructor?

Comment: how do i get  `public TrackerContext() : base("Name=DefaultConnection") {}`  to have a method to pass in `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Environment")`  ?

Comment: Find the code they use to pull the connection string, copy that, then just use  it in your constructor for TrackerContext, passing it along to the base, like so: `public TrackerContext(connectionString) : base(connectionString) {}`